# Obtain an object after Objects Destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```
original = {userName: "pepe", pass: "password", otherFields: "blabla"}
```

I want to destructure it to obtain another object with only one field: userName

If I do:

```
const {userName} = original
console.log(JSON.stringify(userName)) ---> "pepe", but I would like to obtain {userName: "pepe"}
```

Or

```
var newObj = {userName} = original
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj)) ---> {userName: "pepe", pass: "password", otherFields: "blabla"}
```

I would like to obtain `{userName: "pepe"}` after `running JSON.stringify(...)` because it makes me easier to do a `fetch` with this data in the body part.
The only way that I found to do that is the following:

```
const _body = {} 
  _body.userName = original.userName
  body: (JSON.stringify(_body))
```

But when I have more fields to send in the body, I need to add lines to this code. Is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Ugly and not shorter/easier to read(/"better"): `const newObj = {}; ({userName: newObj.userName} = original);` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81qLw0q7/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially when you destructure the value from the object you're getting just that...the value. So in this case `userName` will return the string `"pepe"`. You'll have to pass in a new object literal into your `stringify` call to get the desired result:

```js
const original = { userName: "pepe", pass: "password", otherFields: "blabla" };
const { userName } = original;

console.log(JSON.stringify({ userName }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to eventually need more properties, you could use the rest operator to do this.

```js
const original = {userName: "pepe", pass: "password", otherFields: "blabla"}
    const {pass, otherFields, ...rest} = original

    console.log(JSON.stringify(rest))
```

Only thing is with this route, if you have properties inside original that you may not want into the stringify, you will have to add them to the destructuring so the "rest" operator doesn't pick them up.